# Selecting a value by row number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have the following MySQL table:

```
table_1
id | value_1 | value_2 | value_3
1    hehe      haha      stack
2    over      flow      me
3    123       abc       hello
4    hi        random    php
5    html      js        css
```

How can I select value_2 from 3rd row, which is "abc"?

Something like `$rows[3]['value_2']`

Here's the code I had tried with:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_1 ORDER BY `table_1`.`id` ASC");
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
//And then I tried accessing it by "$rows[3]['value_2']" and $rows['value_2'][3]
```

I can't use `SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id='3'`, because I need to access multiple lines (all of them). I can't use a WHILE loop also, because I need the values in very different places in the code.

Comment: I cant do that because I need to access the values by something like $rows[2]['value_3'], $rows[4]['value_2']. I need to grab all the values, difrent places in the code

Comment: don't use mysql_ functions. Take a look on mysqli or PDO.

Comment: the mysql php module is deprecated and unsafe to use.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array only returns a row corresponding to the query.  The proper use of mysql_fetch_array is as such:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_1 ORDER BY `table_1`.`id` ASC");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    printf("ID: %s  value_2: %s", $row[0], $row[2]);  
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. You can now access them how you wanted.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings ORDER BY `settings`.`id` ASC");
$id=0;
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $settings[$id]['value_1']=$rows['value_1'];
    $settings[$id]['value_2']=$rows['value_2'];
    $settings[$id]['value_3']=$rows['value_3'];
    $id++;
    }

echo $settings[5]['value_3'];
echo $settings[5]['value_1'];
echo $settings[4]['value_2'];
echo $settings[0]['value_3'];
```